# Как загрузить картику из буфера на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Добрый день. Встала задача быстрой загрузки картинок из буфера как вк. Как загружать картинки ajax я разобрался. Но как отловить в нужной форме ctrl+v и достать из буфера картинку, если она там есть я понять не могу. Прошу вашей помощи, буду очень благодарен если прикрепите пример :)

Comment: а как в вк из буфера загружается?

Comment: Если сделать скриншот, а потом в диалоге нажать ctrl+v , то начнется загрузка картинки

Comment: Если именно скриншот, то http://jsfiddle.net/z362aLyb/   и вот так https://jsfiddle.net/8f7d4L7t/  и посложнее http://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/IoJbg

Comment: в фоксе в вк не пашет, даже не знал об таком.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// window.addEventListener('paste', ... or
document.onpaste = function(event){
  var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(items)); // will give you the mime types
  for (index in items) {
    var item = items[index];
    if (item.kind === 'file') {
      var blob = item.getAsFile();
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event){
        console.log(event.target.result)}; // data url!
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
  }
}
```

взято отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338207/2944765